# php: textarea excel paste to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I know this might ma a simple question, it must have been answered before but it's the kind of question you don't know how to google for.

I'm doing an intranet and I have a big texarea in wich te user pastes a 5columns X 365 rows (an optional first column with the 1 to 365 numbers) from excel and ends up in this:

```
1   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
2   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
3   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
4   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
5   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
6   $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285
7   $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285
8   $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285
9   $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285
10  $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285
```

How can I turn this into a php array so I can then insert it into a mysql table?
I tought about using explode() but I'm not sure if the space between each column will always be the same, maybe there's a fancier way to do this.

If this is already discussed somewhere else just point me to it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: of course, the $ would have to be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explode per ligne `'\n'` and then per column `'\t'` and just ignore the `$`

```
<?php
$str = "    1   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
    2   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
    3   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
    4   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
    5   $ 37    $ 74    $ 111   $ 148   $ 185
    6   $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285
    7   $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285
    8   $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285
    9   $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285
    10  $ 57    $ 114   $ 171   $ 228   $ 285";


$arrayCode = array();
$rows = explode("\n", $str);
foreach($rows as $idx => $row)
{
    $row = explode( "\t", $row );

    //to get rid of first item (the number)
    //comment it if you don't need.
    array_shift ( $row );

    foreach( $row as $field )
    {
        //to clean up $ sign
        $field = trim( $field, "$ ");
        $arrayCode[$idx][] = $field;
    }
}
print_r( $arrayCode );
?>
```

Comment: I believe in excel, field is separated by tab upon copy-pasted

Comment: to get rid of **$** and **lines numbers**

Comment: thanks a lot, unfortunately you new code doesnt work. The first one produced this array

 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  37
            [1] =>  74
            [2] =>  111
            [3] =>  148
            [4] =>  185\n 37
            [5] =>  74
            [6] =>  111
            [7] =>  148
            [8] =>  185\n 37

but this version produces an empty array. I'm not finding the reason why I have in a same "row" to valies (number 4 and 8) and the \n

Comment: do'h, dumb me, i didn't change the string var name. Now I get even weird: 

Array
(

    [0] => Array

        (

            [0] => 37
            [1] => 74
            [2] => 111
            [3] => 148
            [4] => 185\n$ 37
            [5] => 74
            [6] => 111
            [7] => 148
            [8] => 185\n$ 37
            [9] => 74